# Why do my clock, indicator applets, and notification area sometimes move around when I restart? How can I prevent that?

Tags: notification, gnome, indicator, clock, session

I have all of them locked to the panel, but they keep moving around upon logging out and back in.  So, for example, sometimes the Indicator Applet Session is farthest to the right, but sometimes the Clock/Calendar is, and occasionally the Notification Area is.  This is a small issue, but annoying.

Comment: The only time that I saw that was when using different monitors, or a remote login (in other words : changing the resolution, and then the layout of the panels).

 Is it your case ?

Comment: Do you use gnome or kde?

Comment: IIRC the Indicator Applet is GNOME-only.

Comment: I'm using GNOME 2.30.2 with Ubuntu 10.04.  I'd guess it has something to do with the fact that I've added Epiphany and gmail-notify to my list of start-up apps, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no real solution except to wait for [bug #44082](https://bugs.launchpad.net/gnome-panel/+bug/44082) to be fixed. However, there is a (very hackish) workaround. Put your panel applets where you want them, then run `gconftool-2 --dump /apps/panel panel_backup.xml`. When the applets get messed up, run

```
 gconftool-2 --load panel_backup.xml
 killall gnome-panel
```

Comment: wouldn't `gnome-panel --replace &` be more apt?

Comment: No, because if you do it this way, you can close the terminal afterwards.

Comment: I've noticed that just running killall gnome-panel often solves this problem for me without the gconftool-2 bit.

Comment: I usually just `Ctrl + Alt + Backspace` to restart X a bit excessive but eh.

Comment: AFAIK, Ctrl + Alt + Backspace does not work in recent Ubuntu releases.

Comment: The Ctrl+Alt+Bksp shortcut was replaced by Alt+SysRq+K.

Answer (score 4):

I use a simpler and more user friendly solution, IMO, than dumping to XML and restoring (which didn't always work for me, btw).

So, the answer to life, universe and everything is (not 42):
1. Install "Lockdown Editor" using Ubuntu Software Center (or whatever you prefer)
2. Launch "Lockdown Editor" under "System->Administration"
3. Under "Panel" enable "Lock down the panels"

Whenever I want to make changes to the panels I disable the setting, make the changes and enable it again. Worked like a charm for me so I hope it helps others too.

Cheers!

Comment: IIRC, there is a "Lockdown all panels" option in Ubuntu Tweak.  I wonder if this option would accomplish the same thing?

Comment: It might. I never used Ubuntu Tweak but I'd say it's a pretty good bet it does just the same. You can also do it with gconf-editor or gconftool-2 directly.

Comment: Yep, the "Lockdown all panels" option in Ubuntu Tweak does the same thing.